# Asterisk channel status

Tags: asterisk, agi

I have Implemented 3 way calling feature using confbridge application from php agi. Now I want to get the channel status of the channel which is in the confbridge (alive or not). I tried using channel_status command from agi some times it is giving me **channel is down and available** even when channel is up. some time it is not returning any value.

Please help me how to get out of this problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If channel status return you "channel down", that mean channel already down(but dialplan still can be working, see h-extension)

There are no way "fix" that, becuase it is not a bug. Likly you just not understand what mean channel down in term of asterisk.

Comment: Thanks for the reply arheops. I understood that and I did some work around to get the channels that are confbridge.